# vue-flatpickr-component has weird styling

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, flatpickr

I'm currently trying to reproduce the "wrap" example shown here: https://ankurk91.github.io/vue-flatpickr-component/ but even when copy-pasting the exact code snippet that I would need (without button styling), I get a weird/shortened picker component

```
<div class="form-group">
          <label>Select date (wrap)</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <flat-pickr v-model="form.date"
                        placeholder="Select date"
                        :config="configs.wrap"
                        :required="true"
                        @on-change="listenToOnChangeEvent"
                        class="form-control"
                        name="date-name"
                        :disabled="inputDisabled"
                        ref="datePickerWrap">
            </flat-pickr>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button type="button" title="Toggle" data-toggle>
                Toggle
              </button>
              <button type="button" title="Clear" data-clear>
                Clear
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

[the first one is a datetimepicker with appended buttons (looks weird and nothing is inline), the second one does not have anything special attached to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EOi6.png)

my code looks like this:

```
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select date (wrap)</label>
        <div class="input-group">
          <flat-pickr ref="datePickerWrap"
                      v-model="registeredAtFrom"
                      :config="configs"
                      :required="true"
                      :disabled="inputDisabled"
                      placeholder="Select date"
                      class="form-control search"
                      name="date-name">
          </flat-pickr>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="button" title="Toggle" data-toggle>
              Toggle
            </button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" title="Clear" data-clear>
              Clear
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <flat-pickr
        v-model="registeredAtTo"
        :config="configs"
        :placeholder="$t('message.searchFields.registeredAtTo')"
        class="form-control search"
        name="date"
      ></flat-pickr>
```

vue-flatpickr-component configs:

```
configs: {
        wrap: true,
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d H:i:S',
        maxDate: new Date(),
        minuteIncrement: 1,
        locale: Hungarian,
        time_24hr: true
      }
```

relevant package.json elements:

```
"vue": "^2.5.2"    
"vue-flatpickr-component": "^8.1.1"    
"vuetify": "^1.2.3"
```

any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Issue tracking is enabled on https://github.com/ankurk91/vue-flatpickr-component so might be best to post on there.

Comment: thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

You sure you have the .css loaded? It should be imported on it's own, right after you import the package:

```
<script>
  import flatPickr from 'vue-flatpickr-component';
  import 'flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.css';

  ...
</script>
```

Comment: yes, I imported the .css as well, and I don't override it anywhere in my code either